Question regarding bases of bilinear forms
Let a bilinear form $\beta \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{(2n+1)})$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and suppose $detH(\beta, A) \neq 0$. Does there exist a basis $A'$ such that $H(\beta, A) = -H(\beta, A’)$
Recall that $[H(\beta, A)](i, j)=\beta(e_i, e_j)$ for any $e_i, e_j \in $ basis $A$
I've tried solving it the following way:
For $n = 0$, $H(\beta, A)$ is a $1$x$1$ matrix, meaning that $H(\beta, A) = -H(\beta, A') = 0$ which contradicts $detH(\beta, A) \neq 0$.
For n > 0, $$-H(\beta, A') \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}-(C^TH(\beta, A)C) \overset{\mathrm{given}}{=} \\ =-(C^T(-H(\beta, A')C) = \\ = C^TH(\beta, A')C = H(\beta, A)$$
But I have a hard time doing anything from here

It seems to me this has to do with the lack of existence of non-degenerate antisymmetric bilinear forms in odd dimension.

in the first paragraph you wrote $H(\beta, A) = -H(\beta, A)$ i.e. $2 H(\beta, A) = \mathbf 0$ with non-zero determinant, so no.  I think you meant $H(\beta, A) = -H(\beta, A')$.  Also just write out the congruence transform and take the determinant -- $- C^T G C =G\implies -1\cdot \det\big(C\big)^2 \cdot \det\big(G\big)=\det\big(G\big)$ which is impossible because...
